# How to save Photoshop slices as rectangles to a text file?

Tags: photoshop, rectangles, photoshop-script

Is it possible to get slice rectangles in pixels using Photoshop scripting? I'd like to be able to save user slice rectangles as text in the following format: `x, y, width, height` for each slice on a new line.

I'm absolutely new to Photoshop scripting, so I don't know how to do it, or if it's possible at all.

Comment: This [link](http://ps-scripts.com/bb/viewtopic.php?t=1445) may be of use to you.

Comment: @GhoulFool This will work for me. Could you repost that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

There is not real way of controlling slices with JavaScript; there are ways around it.

However, this [link](http://ps-scripts.com/bb/viewtopic.php?t=1445) may be of use to you.